# Gmail Mail forwarding

Tags: gmail

I am having emails forwarded to gmail from an Outlook address and a Hotmail address. Is it possible to have these emails forwarded to a specific folder inside of Gmail?

Answer (score 2):

Try these steps:

1. Go to https://mail.google.com
2. In the top right below your Google user icon click the cogwheel icon
3. Select "Settings"
4. Select "Filters"
5. Click "Create a new filter"
6. In the "to:" field enter your Hotmail address
7. Click the blue button with the magnifying glass
8. In the next window check "Apply the label" and in the "Choose label"
   drop-down select the label you want your forwarded Hotmail to go to.
   Note that GMail labels are the same as a folder.
9. Click "Create filter"
10. Test this out

Does this work?

Answer (score 1):

That depends. There are any number of criteria for a filter you can use, depending on how they're forwarded. I'd expect a simple filter for `to:someaddress@hotmail.com` that adds a label and archives the message at the same time should do the trick.

The [Gmail help page on filters](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/6579) should be helpful.

A quick note: Gmail has labels, not folders. It's a subtle but important distinction.